# Do While statement - Two arguments

Tags: java

I have a do while statement, and i want it to loop out when two conditions are met. For some reason, whenever the allUp is true, the loop ends.

```
public void loop(){
    System.out.println(toString());
    do{
        turn();
        System.out.println(toString());
    while(allUp == false && end==false);

    }

}
```

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't even compile. Did you snip too much when you copied it into Stack Overflow?

Comment: besides you code being wrong as described by others, this is expected behavior. the && operator yields true when the expressions on both sides are true. This is no longer the case when allUp == true. (Or am I missing smthg here?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this:

```
while(allUp == false && end==false);

}
```

should be

```
} while(allUp == false && end==false);
```

Comment: @Greg - assuming the question isn't a typo.  I don't think there is a *do* block in Java and it wouldn't compile if the block weren't followed by the while statement.  I think your original answer was spot on.

Answer (score 2):

When `allUp` is true, `allUp == false` is **false** and you exit your loop (one of the two condition is false...). it should be

```
while(allUp == false || end==false);
```

Or, as tvanfosson suggested:

```
while (!(allUp && end))
```

Comment: +1 This is spot on. I think the while inside the do{} was just badly formatted code.

Comment: I would actually prefer it be `while (!allUp || !end)` -- or even `while (!(allUp && end))` since that, IMO, is the clearest expression of continuance while both conditions are not met.   Don't you just love DeMorgan's Law.

Comment: @tvanfosson - thanks. DeMorgan is the exact thing I thought about :)

Answer (score 0):

That looks incorrect. The while should come outside the curly brackets.

```
public void loop(){
System.out.println(toString());
do{
    turn();
    System.out.println(toString());

}    while(allUp == false && end==false);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, the while statement should be outside the curly brace. You might want to read over the [Java Tutorials - While Loops](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) on this topic if you are just starting out in Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

Place the while statement outside the closing brace of your do clause like this:

```
do {
  ...
} while(...);
```

Here, you are checking the condition for the inside the while statement so that when the conditions are true, it loop again; and when false, it exits the loop.

Instead of:

```
do{
    turn();
    System.out.println(toString());
while(allUp == false && end==false);

}
```

Do this:

```
do{
    turn();
    System.out.println(toString());
}    while(allUp == false && end==false);
```